# If a Div or it's children contain a specific string/substring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search

In JQuery/JavaScript, how can I find out if a Div contains a specific string/substring in one of it's child elements? I've looked into both `contains` and `indexOf` but couldn't find any examples of my specific case where I need to commit a different action if a unique string/substring of that string is found.

**Pseudo Code:**

```
if (div contains (itself or child nodes) "this string/part of this string")
then do something
else 
then do something else
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) of div to get all the text of the current div and its childs,

```
if('#divId').text().indexOf("this string/part of this string") != -1)
{

}
else
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$('#yourDiv:contains("search text")').length > 0
```

Alternatively you could do this:

```
$('#yourDiv').text().indexOf("search text") !== -1
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the contains selector and indexOf function are case sensitive so if that matters try:

```
var re = new RegExp( "regex", "i");

if( re.test( $("#div").text() ) ) // returns boolean
```